# iOS: How to dynamically change the color of UI elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, colors, themes

I like to implement a night or dark theme to my application. I already searched the internet, but the existing options aren't what I am looking for. I thought of making my own  "Theming class" for example:

I hava a TableView and I want to change the color of the TableView live (similar to Tweetbot). I thought I could do it this way.

```
    #import "theme.h"
    self.tableview.theme = YES;
```

This should be all I like to implement in my ViewControllers, as easy as possible.

then in theme.m I do all the rest, get the element and them it whenever a NSNotificationCenter message is fired. but the problem is that I am not sure where to start.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but if you want to change colors upon your message, you could do something like

```
    historyTable.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:(0/255.0) green:(255/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1];
```

That will set your tables' color.... if you want to make it fade in and out, there may be a kit to do that, or you could do something like:

```
for(int i=0; i < 50; i++){
    historyTable.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:(i/255.0) green:(255/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1];
}
```

This would fade in the R value in RGB up by 50/255, probably somewhat nicely, but I haven't tested it. Of course, if you just want to jump to another another color, just use the first line.

Comment: This is just basic UIColor stuff, what I want to do is to change all the UI Elements without the need of reloading the ViewController. So basically I send an NSNotificationCenter message and all ViewController who have subscribed to the message will change its UI Elements color according to the current theme. The best way to describe it is how Tweetbot on iOs does it.

Comment: Might as well just pass in the color you want and do             [myElement setColor: myColor]; on all the elements you need then.

Comment: I think that would be a bit to much, I would need to do this in all my .m files. I am sure that it will be a big mess! I think that there is a better way...